# Inverse of numpy's bincount function

Tags: python, numpy

Given an array of integer counts `c`, how can I transform that into an array of integers `inds` such that `np.all(np.bincount(inds) == c)` is true?

For example:

```
>>> c = np.array([1,3,2,2])
>>> inverse_bincount(c)  # <-- what I need

array([0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3])
```

Context: I'm trying to keep track of the location of multiple sets of data, while performing computation on all of them at once. I concatenate all the data together for batch processing, but I need an index array to extract the results back out.

Current workaround:

```
def inverse_bincount(c):
  return np.array(list(chain.from_iterable([i]*n for i,n in enumerate(c))))
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

using  [`numpy.repeat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) :

```
np.repeat(np.arange(c.size), c)
```

Comment: I knew I was missing something really simple! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

no numpy needed :

```
c = [1,3,2,2]
reduce(lambda x,y: x + [y] * c[y], range(len(c)), [])
```

Answer (score 1):

The following is about twice as fast on my machine than the currently accepted answer; although I must say I am surprised by how well np.repeat does. I would expect it to suffer a lot from temporary object creation, but it does pretty well.

```
import numpy as np
c = np.array([1,3,2,2])
p = np.cumsum(c)
i = np.zeros(p[-1],np.int)
np.add.at(i, p[:-1], 1)
print np.cumsum(i)
```

Comment: Nice, but this doesn't work if one of the counts is 0.  Then you have a repeated value in `p`.  Instead of `i[p[:-1]] = 1`, you need to incorporate the number of occurrences of the index in `p`.

Comment: True; changed the code to handle zeros using add.at.

Comment: The current version fails if there are trailing zeros in c (which `np.bincount` does not produce, but they arose in my case). A fix is to replace `p[:-1]` with `p[:np.searchsorted(p,p[-1])]`.